# BufferedWriter newLine method not found

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a BufferedWriter to print several Strings, each on a different Line in a text file. I'm trying to use `out.newLine()` to set a new line for the next string, but I'm getting an error message of `cannot find symbol - method newLine()`

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
Writer out = null;
try {
      out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(start+"2"+dest+".txt"), "utf-8")); // create output file from start names
      out.write(outputOne);//Write Line 1
      out.newLine();
      out.write(outputTwo); //Write Line 2
      out.newLine();
      out.write(outputThree); //Write Line 3
      out.newLine();
      out.write(outputFour); //Write Line 4
      out.close();
 } catch (IOException ex) { //Handle Errors
           System.err.println("Error in BufferedWriter, IOException");
 } finally {
              try {out.close();} 
              catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your variable with a type of `BufferedWriter`. `Writer` does not have a `newLine()` method.

```
BufferedWriter out;
```

Methods are resolved, at compile time, based on the declared/static type of the variable (or expression) they are invoked on.

Alternatively, cast the variable

```
((BufferedWriter)out).write(outputFour);
```

but this is long.

---

Consider using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).